# Bash script as part of package: how to make LaTeX find it

Tags: bash

I'm working on some experimental package that requires LaTeX to execute a Bash script. I'm aware of `-shell-escape`, etc., and it does work if I simply put the script next to the LaTeX file I'm compiling.

However, for distribution, it would be more convenient if I could just put the script into the same folder as the package (.sty) code and run it from there. Does LaTeX provide a way to add a package directory to its own shell search path?

Comment: in TeXlive there is  `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/` and I guess your script associated with package `foo` would be located in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/foo/`.

Comment: Disregard [my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393159/bash-script-as-part-of-package-how-to-make-latex-find-it#comment976907_393160): it’s misleading.  As far as I can tell now, `\write18` does *not* search for the command in any of the TeX input directories, it simply uses the (under UNIX-ish OS’s) the standard `PATH`  environment variable.  Even the scripts stored in the same directory as the `.tex` file executing them are not found unless `.` is part of the current `PATH`.  There is no such thing as (La)TeX “own shell search path” (always AFAICT now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do know not everyone has Bash installed? :)

As jfbu says, it is better to arrange that it is installed into texlive's scripts directory (which will require some code review for security issues for example). However, if it is in the same directory as the .sty file you could call it via an explicit path built from `kpsewhich mypackage.sty` as in:

```
$ `dirname $(kpsewhich colortbl.sty)`/myscript
bash: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/myscript: No such file or directory
```

Which tries (fails in this case) to run `myscript` from the `colortbl` directory.

Comment: Ah of course, `kpsewhich` to the rescue. And yes, I have heard that not everyone does have bash ;) but most of those people will have no use for the package anyway. But I will make a point of it in the docs.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: See also the `TEXMF_RESTRICTED_SCRIPTS` variable in `texmf.cnf`.

Comment: @GuM - OK, thanks. The explanation is a bit sparse in that file, but I will experiment to find out what it means ;)